# How often is Site.js read in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Im wondering if the Site.js file is read just once (on startup) or multiple times (every page) in an ASP.NET Core web application?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you has published the application to the IIS server or else. The stie.js will only be read when you access the page which has site.js reference.

By default,  the site.js is added into the MVC Shared _Layout.cshtml as below:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Any view which use this layout will add the site.js reference. If anyone access this page, the site.js will be read.

Besides, the site.js will not be read in the startup.cs, if you don't have any special settings in your startup.cs(After published to the server).

To check if the site.js has been read or not, you could try to use process monitor to check the site.js has been read or not. You could download it from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

Below is the process monitor result for site.js when restarting the asp.net core application and accessing the home page.

[image]